# How to get a hint when trying to submit a form without filling in a requierd field? (doesn´t work in Firefox mobile)

Tags: firefox, tooltip, submit, contact-form, required

When submitting a form in Firefox mobile without filling in a required field, I´m not getting a hint showing me what field is missing. In Firefox on Windows and Chrome on Android I´m getting a tooltip and the field border is emphasized. On Firefox mobile (android) nothing happens at all.

[Screenshot Firefox on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSyuw.png)

[Screenshot Chrome on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hG70.png)

[Screenshot Firefox on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLGjD.png)

I did try to create a very simple form to assure nothing else in my code was causing this: https://johanstemplate.w3spaces-preview.com/testrequiredform/index.html

A also tried to open the form in incognito mode.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kontaktformulär</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Kontakta oss</h2>
    <form action="https://formspree.io/f/<my_key>" method="post">
        <label for="name">Namn:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br>

        <label for="email">E-post:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>

        <label for="message">Meddelande:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" required></textarea><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Skicka">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my website. The contact form is at the bottom. Two fields are required: Name (namn) and email.
https://johanstemplate.w3spaces.com/

Can I do something different to make it work?